# How to stop users to manipulate the popup and at the same time let googlebot crawl my page

Tags: javascript

I have a very confusing problem.
I have a page which only allow paid users to view it. So if the user is not valid I use a pop up with grey backgroud to block users to view the page however there is a potential flaw with this and if a user is clever he can find a workaround and by using the inspect element bypass the popup. Another solution which comes to my mind is to redirect the user to another page instead of pop up like:

```
window.location = "http://www.example.com";
```

However there is a potential problem with this or may be I am wrong on this: 
I think this way google bots wont be able to crawl that page since redirection happens however in the first approach google will definitely be able to crawl the page.

Now my question is if I use the first approach is there anyway to stop user from manipulating the popup or is there anyway I can distinguish if a user is browsing the page or google?

Also if I use the second approach will google bot be able to crawl the page?

Comment: Sometimes i use the inspect to get around those ad-block popups and paid content warnings. Redirect would be more buletproof

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't implement a paid block or any types of truly secure/working blocking on the frontend. I would suggest prevent accessing to that said page on the backend.

There's no real clean and 100% working way to this on the frontend. The user can always bypass.

For google, it will be able to crawl the page since the content is still accessible via the rendered html, as it does not care how the page is shown. It gets access to the content anyway, just like you would by fetching the html via a get request without a browser.

You could indeed just redirect, but still do it on the backend not the frontend.

Comment: What about the redirecting user to another page instead of pop up but using client side routing. Is there any flaw on that?

Comment: Well not really, but why not do it on the backend? Redirecting with the backend ensures that the user never reaches that page. But with frontend redirect, it gets to your page and could cancel the redirection.  It's not recommended.

Comment: Might be a silly question but this : window.location = "http://www.example.com"; will make a server redirection am I right?

Comment: It makes a request to the location, its just like clicking on anchor tag with an href. But it's not handled as a server side redirection. Hopefully you understand the difference. What i mean by server side is, before sending a response back, you check if the user has access and if not you dont send that said page, but redirect somewhere else, like the index page.

Comment: The problem is I am using Api calls from a third party company and based on what I get via ajax back I will have to make a decision to what to show

Comment: Here's the thing, if its critical that theres no way you can access that said page without being a paid member, you have to implement a server side check, if not i would say its ok to do it on the frontend. When dealing with protected pages/data, even when dealing with a 3RD party api, you should make your own little web server and have those request handled on backend side.

Answer (score 1):

Your current solution does not make the page private - as you rightly point anyone can manipulate the page using the dev tools, and crawlers can read the whole source anyway. Using server-side scripts to block access, and/or vary the content based on an authorisation token is the only way to secure it properly and ensure that only your legitimate paying users get privileged access.

You state a concern about the inability for Google (and other search engines, I assume) to crawl the page if you employ better security. But your logic is flawed: If you make it so that a google bot can still crawl the page, then by definition it must be readable without authorisation. Anyone could view it in the google cache, and parts of its content could show up in google searches. This means it isn't private. Once that's the case, then what are your users paying for, exactly?

What you might realistically want to do is have a cut-down version of the page that is displayed when the user is not authorised, containing enough information for search engines to get an idea of the overall content, and for visitors to be tempted into paying for the rest. Then if the user logs in, the server recognises that and displays the rest of the content as well when the page refreshes. That appears to be roughly what paid-content news sites do, for instance.

Comment: What about the redirecting user to another page instead of pop up but using client side routing. Is there any flaw on that?

Comment: Do you mean you will do this once the user is authorised and identified as a paid user? Since you have to do that process on the server, you might as well do the redirection on the server as well. Otherwise, you just end up with more round-trips to the server than you really need. I'm unclear why you are so interested in doing things client-side - as I've explained, you cannot rely for security on anything that happens client-side, it can all be removed or tampered with by a knowledgable user.

Comment: I think what I describe in my 3rd paragraph is your best option - make a small amount of your content public to allow search engines and users to find it, and make them tempted to pay for the rest. Then force the user log in. Authenticate & authorise them on the server-side, and then either a) redirect to the real content (ensuring it checks the user's credentials before loading), or return to the same URL but use server-side script to check the credentials and allow extra content to be displayed.

Comment: The problem is I am using Api calls from a third party company and based on what I get via ajax back I will have to make a decision to what to show

Comment: In that case don't use ajax to make the API calls to the 3rd party. Do that on the server-side, then you can keep the result of that call private and decide what to show before anything ever reaches the browser.